# String pooling after alteration of String

Tags: java, string

I have this code

```
String a="test";
String b="test";
if(a==b)
   System.out.println("a == b");
else
   System.out.println("Not True");
```

And every Java experts knows that here `if(a==b)` will be passed due to [String pooling facility](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).
According to String pooling 
`Each time your code creates a string literal, the JVM checks the string literal pool first. If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance is returned. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object is created and placed in the pool. JVM keeps at most one object of any String in this pool. String literals always refer to an object in the string pool`
*And thats why in above code the condition has passed.*
**Now Here comes the question**.In the above code when I added two additional lines `a+="1"` and `b+="1"` then now the values of String a & b would be `Test1`.
The new code would be like this

```
String a="test";
    String b="test";
    if(a==b)
        System.out.println("a == b");
    else
        System.out.println("Not True");
        a+="1"; //it would be test1 now
        b+="1"; //it would also be test1 now
    if(a==b)
       System.out.println("a == b");
    else
      System.out.println("Not True");
```

Now after altering the strings, when I placed the `if(a==b)` check then it didn't passed.I know this is due to immutability feature of String But I want to know
**1)** After altering, Does JVM store them with two Different objects?
**2)** Does JVM call `new String()` for alteration of any String?
**3)** Why they are not referencing as a single even I tried to call `intern()` while alteration?
 *Q3 Hint:* 
 `a+="1".intern();`
            `b+="1".intern();`

Comment: @ThomasW if you are thinking this even after such a detailed explanation then I really want pray for your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, that's why `a == b` fails. These new strings are not part of the string pool as they weren't literals from the beggining.

2) As pointed out by @LuiggiMendoza, it will use the String constructor if the compiler has a way to know the values of the Strings, otherwise it will rather use a `StringBuilder` internally (which at the end of the day it will use a String constructor to return the final String)

3) Even if "1" is a literal, the result of `a + "1".intern();` itself is not a literal, but a new String object created with a String constructor, so it is not added to the String pool.

Comment: For point 2, this is true only if the `String` value can be known at compile time.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and if it was not known then?

Comment: @morgano Please clarify point 3.Actually I want to know why intern() fails to put them in string pool?

Comment: @freak then it will create a new `String` object.

Comment: @freak I clarified point 3 as much as I can, the think is that in (String a = "x"; String b = "y"; String c = a + b) A and B conains literals, but C ("xy") never was a literal, it was built at runtime

Comment: @freak See my response.  It may help.

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are immutable.  After *altering* a string, your variable will now reference a different`String`.

When creating a `new String`, JVM uses `StringBuilder` if the value(s) is/are not known at compile time; otherwise, the standard `String` constructor is used.

When adding `"1".intern()`, the `.intern()` applies to the `"1"` (**not** `a + "1"`); the concatenation produces new `String` objects (**NOT** literals), so `a` and `b` do not reference the same objects.  Remember, when `Strings` are created through the `new` operator, you force new memory to be allocated.

In order for `a` and `b` to actually reference the same object, you would have to call `.intern()` on both of them:

```
_a = _a.intern(); //adds _a to the String pool
_b = _b.intern(); //makes _b point to the same object as _a, since _b.equals(_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because when you do '+=' then it creates a new object on the heap not in String pool due to String immutability. If you want it in String pool then again call **[intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)** method on both Strings.

```
String a="test";
    String b="test";
    if(a==b)
        System.out.println("a == b");
    else
        System.out.println("Not True");
        a+="1"; //it would be test1 now
        b+="1"; //it would also be test1 now

       a=a.intern();
       b=b.intern();

    if(a==b)
       System.out.println("a == b");
    else
      System.out.println("Not True");
```

Now it will produce 'a == b' in both cases. For more information on String pooling go to this [link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/strings/string-literal-pool/).